# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 107: invalid start byte

Tags: python, xml, tensorflow

Following [this tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) im stuck on [.xml to .record conversion](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#convert-xml-to-record).

In fact, when i use the following query :

```
C:\XXXX\scripts\processing>python generate_tfrecord.py -x C:/XXXX/workspace/training_demo/images/train -l C:/XXXX/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o C:/XXXX/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record
```

This does return me :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 107: invalid start byte
```

**the .xml are like this :**

```
<annotation>
    <folder>train</folder>
    <filename>XXXX.PNG</filename>
    <path>C:\XXXX\workspace\training_demo\images\train\XXXX.PNG</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>93</width>
        <height>66</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>XXXX</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>1</ymin>
            <xmax>93</xmax>
            <ymax>66</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

and the code is exactly the same as in the tutorial :

```
""" Sample TensorFlow XML-to-TFRecord converter

usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-x XML_DIR] [-l LABELS_PATH] [-o OUTPUT_PATH] [-i IMAGE_DIR] [-c CSV_PATH]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -x XML_DIR, --xml_dir XML_DIR
                        Path to the folder where the input .xml files are stored.
  -l LABELS_PATH, --labels_path LABELS_PATH
                        Path to the labels (.pbtxt) file.
  -o OUTPUT_PATH, --output_path OUTPUT_PATH
                        Path of output TFRecord (.record) file.
  -i IMAGE_DIR, --image_dir IMAGE_DIR
                        Path to the folder where the input image files are stored. Defaults to the same directory as XML_DIR.
  -c CSV_PATH, --csv_path CSV_PATH
                        Path of output .csv file. If none provided, then no file will be written.
"""

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import argparse

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
from collections import namedtuple

# Initiate argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Sample TensorFlow XML-to-TFRecord converter")
parser.add_argument("-x",
                    "--xml_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input .xml files are stored.",
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument("-l",
                    "--labels_path",
                    help="Path to the labels (.pbtxt) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-o",
                    "--output_path",
                    help="Path of output TFRecord (.record) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i",
                    "--image_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input image files are stored. "
                         "Defaults to the same directory as XML_DIR.",
                    type=str, default=None)
parser.add_argument("-c",
                    "--csv_path",
                    help="Path of output .csv file. If none provided, then no file will be "
                         "written.",
                    type=str, default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.image_dir is None:
    args.image_dir = args.xml_dir

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)


def xml_to_csv(path):
    """Iterates through all .xml files (generated by labelImg) in a given directory and combines
    them in a single Pandas dataframe.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    path : str
        The path containing the .xml files
    Returns
    -------
    Pandas DataFrame
        The produced dataframe
    """

    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    return label_map_dict[row_label]


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(args.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(args.image_dir)
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    print('Successfully created the TFRecord file: {}'.format(args.output_path))
    if args.csv_path is not None:
        examples.to_csv(args.csv_path, index=None)
        print('Successfully created the CSV file: {}'.format(args.csv_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

and there is the **label_map.pbtxt** file

```
item {
  id: 21
  name: 'XXXX'
}
item {
  id: 31
  name: 'XXXX'
}
item {
  id: 41
  name: 'XXXX'
}
```

**Full consol returns :**

```
C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.JPIJNSWNNAN3CE6LLI5FWSPHUT2VXMTH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.QVLO2T66WEPI7JZ63PS3HMOHFEY472BC.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 61, in <module>
    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\XXXX\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 168, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 107: invalid start byte
```

**EDIT here is label_map**

```
item {
  id: 21
  name: '2Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 31
  name: '3Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 41
  name: '4Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 51
  name: '5Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 61
  name: '6Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 71
  name: '7Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 81
  name: '8Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 91
  name: '9Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 101
  name: '10Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 111
  name: '11Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 121
  name: '12Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 131
  name: '13Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 141
  name: '14Carreau'
}
item {
  id: 22
  name: '2Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 32
  name: '3Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 42
  name: '4Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 52
  name: '5Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 62
  name: '6Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 72
  name: '7Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 82
  name: '8Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 92
  name: '9Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 102
  name: '10Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 112
  name: '11Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 122
  name: '12Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 132
  name: '13Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 142
  name: '14Coeur'
}
item {
  id: 23
  name: '2Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 33
  name: '3Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 43
  name: '4Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 53
  name: '5Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 63
  name: '6Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 73
  name: '7Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 83
  name: '8Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 93
  name: '9Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 103
  name: '10Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 113
  name: '11Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 123
  name: '12Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 133
  name: '13Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 143
  name: '14Trefle'
}
item {
  id: 24
  name: '2Pic'
}
item {
  id: 34
  name: '3Pic'
}
item {
  id: 44
  name: '4Pic'
}
item {
  id: 54
  name: '5Pic'
}
item {
  id: 64
  name: '6Pic'
}
item {
  id: 74
  name: '7Pic'
}
item {
  id: 84
  name: '8Pic'
}
item {
  id: 94
  name: '9Pic'
}
item {
  id: 104
  name: '10Pic'
}
item {
  id: 114
  name: '11Pic'
}
item {
  id: 124
  name: '12Pic'
}
item {
  id: 134
  name: '13Pic'
}
item {
  id: 144
  name: '14Pic'
}
```

---

Now I use this query :

```
C:\####\workspace\training_demo>python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

It started well but, throw the same issue at the end, I checked `pipeline.config` and `model_main_tf2` but your answer did not correct this one... Do you have any idea ?

```
2021-03-03 09:53:43.878440: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.745301: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-03 09:53:48.749824: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.779768: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 19 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2021-03-03 09:53:48.786205: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.800110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.803731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.812755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.822516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.837930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.851302: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.856177: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.860712: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-03 09:53:48.863378: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-03 09:53:48.873474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 19 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2021-03-03 09:53:48.881298: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.884006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.887551: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.891894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.895372: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.898176: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.903001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.906421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-03 09:53:48.910388: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-03 09:53:49.506138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-03 09:53:49.509246: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
2021-03-03 09:53:49.511875: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
2021-03-03 09:53:49.513745: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6278 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2021-03-03 09:53:49.521636: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0303 09:53:49.527721 12968 mirrored_strategy.py:350] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\####\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\####\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\####\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 474, in train_loop
    configs = get_configs_from_pipeline_file(
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\anaconda3\envs\####\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 138, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 102: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The error says that your XML file contains non utf-8 encoded data. Unfortunately, you did not show us what exists near the byte 127 of the xml file. Worse, you did not give the full error message specifically what line in the code raised the error. We **need** that to help you.

Comment: @SergeBallesta How would i know what ecist near the byte 127 of xml file ? Its plenty of  small .xml like the one in exemple (always the same structure) and the goal of my python query is to merge them and to build a .record file i guess

Comment: At least you should give the full error message *with the line raising the error*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added all I had... Where could I find more information ? I am using trying to use `tensorflow` but this error is throw and I don't know where to find why this issue is generated... so where should I search since i provided all the consol  output..
Kindly and thanks for your help

Comment: After reading the full error message, I think that the problem is in the label_map file. It probably contains non ASCII characters, and is not utf8 encoded.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added the file label_map  by editing the issue, do you see anormal stuff ?  Is it due to `'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your file seems correct, but it contains APOSTROPHE characters (`'` U+27). In cp1252 encoding, 0x92 is the encoding of the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’` U+2019). Some word processors are clever enough to know that in normal texts right and left quotation marks look nicer than the English apostrophe or quotation mark (`"`) and they tend to replace them automatically.

Unfortunately it is not easy to identify them when reading a text file.

So you should control twice whether you text files contains some of those characters

- ’ U+2019 cp1252: 0x92 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- ‘ U+2018 cp1252: 0x91 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- ” U+201d cp1252: 0x94 RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
- “ UX201c cp1252: 0x93 LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK

Comment: Still the same character. But now the error is inside tf processing, so the offending character is probably in one of your data files. You should try to read all of them in Python line by line as utf-8 and show the file and line in an error message. I cannot say more here...